# How is this the definition of equi-integrable?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, definition, uniform-integrability

Let $Q=(0,T)\times\Omega.$ I am completely lost with this:

[image]

No definition of equi-integrability I have seen looks anything like this. Can someone help me please? Presumably it is a fact that a sequence being equiintegrable implies convergence in $L^1$. (Let us just take $p=p'=2$). Here we can assume that $u_\delta \in L^2(Q)$ if need be.

Source is [this paper](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~porretta/papers/Blanchard-Porretta-JDE.pdf) on page 426.

Comment: Looks like Simon's criterion for precompactness in $L^1$; as at the bottom of the first page [here](http://math.unice.fr/~jsimon/pubs/Simon-E3.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. Provided $u_\delta$ are bounded in $L^2(0,T;H^1)$ it seems to me that (A.5) is enough to apply the criterion. Don't need (A.6).

Comment: Provided $H^1$ is compactly embedded in $L^1$...

Comment: Which it is, by [Rellich-Kondrachov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem).